# When I run it on my device, the cardview doesn't display, only a blank activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I was wondering what is the problem with my card view because I try several options that I found like hardware acceleration="true" or app:compatPadding="true". thanks for answering my question.cheers

[My layout in my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39ggg.png)
[My layout when I run it on emulator/device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFxif.png)

Here's my code snippet of card view which has the same code:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/bg_top_header"
    android:layout_width="414dp"
    android:layout_height="167dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_color"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bg_top_header"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/cardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/camera"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Image"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/cardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/fire_sprinkler"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice"
                android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/cardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/sms_sent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DM"
                android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/tick"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_heigt="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alarm"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/register_bk_color"
        android:onClick="onLogout"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_img" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is that your full code? I don't see 4 images

Comment: @Avital no it's just a code snippet, cause all four of them have the same  code that I use in creating a card view

Comment: post all of it so we can try run it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `CardView`'s `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/cardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```